# Is AngularJS Routing only used with ng-view?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

As far as I understand, AngularJS routing configuration is required if you want to use ng-view for Single Page Application (SPA).

My question: if I am not building SPA, and I dont configure routing, can I still use $routeProvider to get URL parameters?

Comment: The app will not stop you from accessing the $routeProvider in config but if you app grows a little big it will be come unmanageable without router. Router surely recommended. Try this if you want a scaled router. ngRoute of angular is restrictive. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Thanks Gary, but that is not what I am asking. My question is - AngularJS routing can only be used with SPA, only with ng-view?

Comment: I believe yes. I have not used in others. But I believe it is not the case with Angular2

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want any routing  but you want  parameters from the url. you could use the dependency, $routeparams. this might be a better solution then using the routeprovider since you don't want to have an actual spa.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can inject the $stateProvier but you can't see any parameters if you don't register any state to navigate between pages.

example: http://embed.plnkr.co/9t3jwYxECN7GV8c3wDSl/